# python requests authenticate to google via SSO (CAS/Shibboleth)

Tags: python, python-requests, google-docs, cas, shibboleth

An institution I work with uses Google services including gmail, docs, sheets, etc. The institution relies on CAS for all authentication, and accessing a Google resource that requires authentication sends me through various redirects and authentication methods before taking me to the actual resource.

For example, I have a google doc that is shared with me. If I hit the doc url in a private browser, I am redirected to a google login page, on which I enter my institution email address (does not ends in @gmail.com), click next, then, instead of moving along to the standard google password page, I'm routed to an institution hosted CAS login page, on which I enter my username and password, then I am redirected to the resource. Inspecting the network traffic seems to reveal that I am routed through an institution-hosted Shibboleth service between the CAS authentication and the redirect to the actual doc.

I am struggling to get through this programatically. I'm currently using python with requests (session). I have no problem getting through the regular institution CAS service. For example, if an institution website includes a page the requires CAS authentication, I can authenticate to the website via CAS through python/requests (session), after which I can access the protected page programatically. This Google authentication maze, on the other hand, is proving much more difficult.

I know that there are OAuth methods of authenticating to google, and event google API libraries for interacting with google services. I cannot, however, find any trace of information relating to this specific issue of authenticating to Google through a third-party SSO/CAS/Shibboleth setup. I'm sure there's some info/knowledge out there, but I'm struggling to find it. While in a browser I only have to enter my institution email address on the initial google login form, after which clicking next will send to my familiar CAS login form, I am unable to get past this google login step programmatically. Since the "Next" button is a javascript function that seems to analyze my email address, notice it doesn't end in "@gmail", then send me off to the SSO corresponding to the email domain, I can't seem to replicate this chain of events in python.  So, I hit the email-entry form for google, fill out the form my email and all the other required/hidden fields, then post that date back to the same url, since the form has no action attribute. Once I do this, I am send to the regular google password page, whose form now has some handy hidden session/hash field/value pairs. But, I should be sent to CAS instead of the password page. Anyways, I've tried entering a password there (with all the other form fields) and submitting it back to itself, but it just loads the same password form page again without ever forwarding me on to CAS

Any assistance or shared experience is greatly appreciated.